# MongoDB Python Update/ Insert dict in dict without overwriting

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary

I can't insert my new document value (dict) without overwriting my existing data. I've looked through all different resources and can't find an answer.
I've also though of putting the values from `first_level_dict` into a list `"first_level_dict" : [dict1, dict2]` but I won't know how to append the dict eighter.

## Sample Data:

```
# Create the document

target_dict = {
    "_id": 55,
    "Root_dict": {
        "first_level_dict": {
            "second_level_dict1": {"Content1": "Value1"}
        }
    },
    "Root_key": "Root_value"
}
collection.insert_one(target_dict)
```

## The result I'm looking for:

```
result_dict = {
    "_id": 55,
    "Root_dict": {
        "first_level_dict": {
            "second_level_dict1": {"Content1": "Value1"},
            "second_level_dict2": {"Content2": "Value2"}
        }
    },
    "Root_key": "Root_value"
}
```

## Update: New Values example 2:

```
# New Values Sample

new_values = {
    "_id": 55,
    "Root_dict": {
        "first_level_dict": {
        "secon_level_dict2": {"Content2": "Value2"},
        "secon_level_dict3": {"Content3": "Value3"}
        }
    }
    collection.insert_one(target_dict)
```

## Update: The result I'm looking for example 2:

```
result_dict = {
    "_id": 55,
    "Root_dict": {
        "first_level_dict": {
            "second_level_dict1": {"Content1": "Value1"},
            "second_level_dict2": {"Content2": "Value2"},
            "second_level_dict3": {"Content3": "Value3"},
        }
    },
    "Root_key": "Root_value"
}
```

## What I've tried:

```
# Update document "$setOnInsert"
q = {"_id": 55}
target_dict = {"$set": {"Root_dict": {"first_level_dict": {"second_level_dict2": {"Content2": "Value2"}}}}}
collection.update_one(q, target_dict)
```

## What I've tried example 2:

```
# Update document
q = {"_id": 55}
target_dict = {"$set": {"Root_dict.first_level_dict": {
    "second_level_dict2": {"Content2": "Value2"},
    "second_level_dict3": {"Content3": "Value3"}}}}
collection.update_one(q, target_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation):

```
target_dict = {$set: {"Root_dict.first_level_dict.second_level_dict2": {"Content2": "Value2"}}}
```

Additionally, to update/add multiple fields (for "example 2"):

```
target_dict = {$set: {
    "Root_dict.first_level_dict.second_level_dict2": {"Content2": "Value2"},
    "Root_dict.first_level_dict.second_level_dict3": {"Content3": "Value3"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, that is definitely news for me and very helpful information! It works using the . operator! Are there other ways you know of, just for curiosity?

Comment: I don't know about other methods, but this worked for me after checking the mongodb docs and testing it in the console. I'm glad I could help you out, please consider marking my answer as accepted if it worked for you ;)

Comment: Sure I will, I was just in-depth testing your solution. I found one thing I'm stumbling over. As soon as I have more values in the dict like in my updated question example 2 I overwrite it with your used method again. :/

Comment: That's odd, it works in the console for me. Did you change the values according to what you would like to add using the target_dict? e.g. for Example 2 to you should use {$set: {"Root_dict.first_level_dict.second_level_dict1": {"Content1": "Value1"}}}
If you use a field that already exists in the dictionary, the value of that field will be overwritten (but the rest won't).

Comment: I've written in what I've tried in "What I've tried example 2". I want to add two new dicts as key:value pairs. `second_level_dict2`, `second_level_dict3`.

Comment: Just separate all field : value pairs with commas, using the dot notation. I've updated my answer for your second example. If you're interested in learning more about updating fields, go check out the official [documentation for $set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/).